# How do you cut and paste a row to another sheet using Java Apps Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have attached the following link to my Google spreadsheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wIaBnGmq-UG9UvAP9X4o-svo_SO1SElUhx6TSpdjgZw/edit?usp=sharing)

In the sheet called "Qualifications" is a list of employees and personal data. When an employee leaves, the user will click the "Employee Left" button which opens up Column B. The intention is that the user will then add next to the employee's name, the date the employee left and once the user presses enter the respective row will be cut and pasted into the sheet titled "Qualifications - Employees Left" and Column B will be hidden again. This is my way of trying to archive the data and still have access to it just in case the employee returns.

I have started an apps script on row 194 of the Script Editor. I was initially going to just hide the row but I don't want all of the little arrows when a row is hidden in Google Sheets. I am now struggling with the code and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

(1) Unhide column B when the button `Employee Left` is clicked (in `Qualifications`).

(2) If the user writes a date in the column `Date Left` (in `Qualifications`), all the data in the corresponding row getting cut & paste to the first empty row in `Qualifications - Employees Left`, and column B gets hidden again.

I modified your script so that it accomplishes these tasks.

First, it looks like the function `EmployeeLeft` you wrote already does what it's supposed to do, but I reworked it a bit. I'm not sure why you want to activate and then unhide column C, but anyway, whatever suits you. This is the one I wrote:

```
function EmployeeLeft() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var colIndex = 2;
  sheet.showColumns(colIndex);
  sheet.getRange("B5").activate();
}
```

Then comes the main part. In order to accomplish point (2), I wrote a function inside an `onEdit` trigger. I am aware you already have an `onEdit` function, but I think there shouldn't be any problem integrating this code inside it.

Basically, this function checks whether the edited cell is from sheet `Qualifications`, from `column B`, not from a header row, and that the edited value is a valid [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If all these conditions are met, the edited row is removed from `Qualifications` and its values are copied to the first empty row in `Qualifications - Employees Left`. Finally, `column B` becomes hidden again, until `Employee Left` is clicked again.

Here is the function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = "Qualifications"
  var range = e.range;
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var column = 2;
  var date = range.getValue();
  // Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]' --> checks if value is date
  // editedColumn == column && editedRow > 4 --> checks if edited cell is from 'Date Left'
  // sheet.getName() == sheetName --> checks if edited sheet is 'Qualifications'
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]' && editedColumn == column && editedRow > 4 && sheet.getName() == sheetName) {
    var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var row = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, numCols).getValues();
    var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Qualifications - Employees Left");
    // Get first empty row:
    var emptyRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    // Copy values from 'Qualifications'
    destinationSheet.getRange(emptyRow, 1, 1, numCols).setValues(row);
    sheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
    sheet.hideColumns(column);
  }
}
```

Take into account that there is some data in some rows far below the headers in "Qualifications - Employees Left". Make sure that you remove all these data so that values get copied in the appropriate rows.

## Update

Here I share a copy of the spreadsheet with the correct script attached. I'd advice you to copy the full script and paste it in the file you're working on, removing all previous content:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCrcSaDwwmKTHLIxL9vbx0_t6NJew983d9YDol-Y1dw/edit?usp=sharing

- The function `onEdit(e)` is added on top, including both, the one I wrote and the one you had already written.
- Regarding the function `Employee Left`, I commented out the one you wrote and added mine below. If you prefer yours, just remove mine and uncomment yours.

I hope this is of any help, and please tell me if that works for you.

Comment: That works - thank you but my other onEdit functions don't work anymore. Have I missed something?

Comment: You have to integrate both codes in one edit function. There can only be one onEdit function, otherwise only one will run. And don't forget to pass it the event parameter, as in 'onEdit(e)'

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do either of those functions. I have added your script to the editor in the shared spreadsheet. Can you make the corrections and point out what you have done so I know for next time?

Comment: @McChief, I updated my answer with a copy of the spreadsheet that includes the full code. I'd advice you to copy all this code and paste it to the script of the file you're working on, removing all previous content. I hope that finally works for you.

Comment: I can't see the code because the sheet is 'View Only' and I can't open the Script Editor. I have requested access.

Comment: You should [make a copy of the spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/49114?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Anyway, I've granted you access.

Comment: That's perfect - thank you very much for all of your help. Very grateful.

Comment: I just found that when I remove an Employee from the Qualifications Sheet it creates a "#REF!" issue in the FormRanger sheet and now have #REF! in my dropdowns. If an employee leaves, I want the names (currently #REF!in the Form Ranger removed

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. And what you're asking now is a totally different question. I'd advice you to create a new question for that.

Comment: @ Iamblichus - Okay - will do. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete complete the row with active cell, and add it to the new sheet at the end. Remember to replace the values containing <> with actual ones.

```
function remove_and_reinsert_row() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange();
   var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
   var tbd_row_data = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 1, 1,last_column).getValues();
   sheet.deleteRow(active_range.getRowIndex());

   var new_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("existing sheet name");
   var last_active_row = new_sheet.getLastRow();
   new_sheet.getRange(last_active_row+1, 1, 1,tbd_row_data[0].length).setValues(tbd_row_data);
}
```

This will use row with active range, i.e. and cell which is currently active and delete the row , inserting it into new sheet. You can use trigger on the column and see whenever someone changes value in the column, and trigger the function using app script triggers.

For hiding a column, you can use following function:

```
  sheet.hideCoumns(colIndex);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you - when I save the script in the script editor I get this message "Illegally formed XML syntax. (line 220, file "Code")Dismiss". This line is the closing bracket of the script.

Comment: That's because you have to replace the following in the code, i left them for you to replace:
1. <col_no_to start> - with the start column for the table in new sheet, mostly it will be 1.
2. <new sheet sheet_name> - with the name of new sheet which will be the sheet in which you will save the employees that left.

Comment: I changed the name but not the start column - sorry. I have now changed the column number to 1 because I want the data to move to the new sheet from column A. It still doesn't work.

Comment: your both sheets, (one from which you are removing and one in which you are inserting) are in same spreadsheet right ? 
I have edited the code, just change the "existing sheet name" here to sheet where you want to add row. Also, when you run the function make sure the sheet from which you are removing has active cell( the blue highlight cell on sheet) on one of the columns of the row which is to be removed.

Comment: sorry - still doesn't work. Yes, both sheets are in the same spreadsheet. I changed the name of the sheet in your code to the name of the sheet that the data is being extracted from but nothing happens.

Comment: Okay! tell me any channel where i can share a video. I'll share a running video of this one. maybe that'll help